# How to auto-unlock IOS device protected via a passcode when connecting it to Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have password pin on my iPhone and whenever I want to try my new build I have to manually unload the device. Is it possible to unlock device from Xcode automatically? Something like insert password pin into keychain. Thx for reply.

Comment: I don't think you can since we are suppose to use devices without passcode dedicated to development only.

Comment: You cant achieve that

Comment: Similar question here with some advices http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129631/putting-iphone-passcode-into-xcode-so-i-wouldnt-need-to-unlock-my-iphone-for-e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anyway to do so, but you can prevent locking the device by the following trick:

- Go to Home Screen ==> Settings
- Open General
- Tap Auto-Lock
- Select Never

Also the another trick is the following:

- Go to Home Screen ==> Settings
- Open [Touch ID and] Passcode
- Tap Require Password
- Select a longer interval

The another way is to disable passcode on the device.

Important Note: Disable all this settings after developing is finished (for security).

Note: If your device is jailbroken, you can set this settings to enable when booting up the device. Search Cydia to find out more.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible without jailbreak.

Fix Radar or GTFO!

The only way is to report the bug to
[Apple Bug Reporter System](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login.html?appIdKey=77e2a60d4bdfa6b7311c854a56505800be3c24e3a27a670098ff61b69fc5214b&sslEnabled=true&rv=3) ,

and then report to here [openradar](http://openradar.appspot.com/page/1)  so we can see the bugs list at there.

You can see the same Radar at here:
[Fix Radar or GTFO](http://fixradarorgtfo.com)

If you are Chinese ,you can read [Apple Bug Reporter System](http://www.cocoachina.com/apple/20150128/11055.html)